# Combing two character vectors iteratively

Tags: r, character

I need to combine two character vectors so that my final vector has a length equal to length(a) * length(b).

Vector 1: "Bob" "Amy" "Jan"
Vector 2: "H", "M", "L"

Output: "Bob H" "Bob M" "Bob L" "Amy H" "Amy M" "Amy L" "Jan H" "Jan M" "Jan L"

code:

```
vec1 <- c("Bob", "Amy", "Jan")
vec2 <- c("H", "M", "L")

vec3 <- ??operation??(vec1, vec2)
```

Any consideration is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `outer` with `paste`

```
c(outer(vec1, vec2, paste))
#[1] "Bob H" "Amy H" "Jan H" "Bob M" "Amy M" "Jan M" "Bob L" "Amy L" "Jan L"
```

**data**

```
vec1 <- c("Bob", "Amy", "Jan")
vec2 <- c("H", "M", "L")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not insist to have character vector as output, cross join is another option:

```
merge(vec1, vec2)

#    x y
#1 Bob H
#2 Amy H
#3 Jan H
#4 Bob M
#5 Amy M
#6 Jan M
#7 Bob L
#8 Amy L
#9 Jan L
```